# Issues with Http Post despite enabling CORS in both Elm and Giraffe

Tags: f#, cors, elm, asp.net-core-webapi

I have been struggling to enable cross domain requests between my Elm client and a Giraffe server.

**Elm (Client):**

```
tryPostRegistration : String -> Http.Body -> Decoder JsonProfile -> Http.Request JsonProfile
tryPostRegistration url body decoder =
    Http.request
        { method = "POST"
        , headers =
            [ header "Origin" "http://elm-lang.org"
            , header "Access-Control-Request-Method" "POST"
            , header "Access-Control-Request-Headers" "X-Custom-Header"
            ]
        , url = url
        , body = body
        , expect = Http.expectJson decoder
        , timeout = Nothing
        , withCredentials = False
        }


tryRegister : Form -> (Result Http.Error JsonProfile -> msg) -> Cmd msg
tryRegister form msg =
    let
        url =
            baseUrl ++ "register"

        body =
            encodeRegistration form |> Http.jsonBody

        request =
            tryPostRegistration url body profileDecoder
    in
        Http.send msg request
```

*Error (Elm client):*

> HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the
>   requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).(XHR)OPTIONS -
>   http://localhost:5000/register

**Giraffe (Server):**

```
let configureCors (builder : CorsPolicyBuilder) =
    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5000").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader() |> ignore

let configureApp (app : IApplicationBuilder) =
    app.UseCors configureCors |> ignore
    app.UseGiraffe webApp

let configureServices (services : IServiceCollection) =
    ...
    services.AddCors |> ignore // Enables CORS
```

*Error (Giraffe server):*

> dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[1](https://github.com/bizmonger/Nikeza/blob/master/Client/app/Services/Gateway.elm)
>         OPTIONS requests are not supported
>
> dbug: Giraffe.Middleware.GiraffeMiddleware[0]
>         Giraffe returned Some for HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS /register

**Appendix:**

[Elm Gateway (with CORS support)](https://github.com/bizmonger/Nikeza/blob/master/Client/app/Services/Gateway.elm)

[Giraffe server (with CORS support)](https://github.com/bizmonger/Nikeza/blob/master/Server/Nikeza.Server/Startup.fs)

[Giraffe CORS sample project reference](https://github.com/dustinmoris/Giraffe/blob/develop/samples/IdentityApp/IdentityApp/Program.fs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the time to check a bit more and cannot find any route in your code or the Giraffe code with an options route. In C# Asp.Net core I've used:

```
    public IActionResult GetOptions()
    {
        Response.Headers.Add("Allow", "GET, OPTIONS, POST");
        return Ok();
    }
```

So I think you need to add something like this on GET:

```
route  "/options" >=> setHttpHeader "Allow" "GET, OPTIONS, POST"
```

I'v not tried Giraffe yet, so I've not been able to test if this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
let configureCors (builder : CorsPolicyBuilder) =
    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5000").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader() |> ignore
```

this bit says "allow cross origin requests if the origin is http://localhost:5000. However, you seem to be using `elm-live` on the default port, which is 8000. So effectively, your server is denying requests from port 8000.

Long story short, change that to say `http://localhost:8000`. If that doesn't fix it, fingers crossed someone with actual F# knowledge can help further.

---

```
headers =
    [ header "Origin" "http://elm-lang.org"
    , header "Access-Control-Request-Method" "POST"
    , header "Access-Control-Request-Headers" "X-Custom-Header"
    ]
```

this bit won't really do anything - the browser sets these by itself. Elm's HTTP library uses your browser's XMLHttpRequest implementation, and XMLHttpRequest isn't allowed to set those headers, so they'll be ignored. https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-namer lists headers you aren't allowed to override.

Comment: Thanks. I made the update that you suggested. However, I still receive the same error.

Comment: Seems like you are using cookie auth. You may need to add ..AllowCredentials() to configureCors according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors - I had to do this when using Windows authentication.

Comment: Also - Check the pre-flight request and response in the browser devtools network tab(or Fiddler) and verify if it's according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors (How CORS works). Have you tried different browsers?